# Big queryにてスプレッドシートのデータをインポートしたい

Tags: google-cloud, google-bigquery

bigqueryにおいてスプレッドシートのデータをインポートしたのですが、以下の文章がでます。
なぜでしょうか。

Failed to create table: Invalid field name "". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

日本語のデータはインポートできないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

日本語とか項目名に入れてたりしないですか？データとしては日本語大丈夫ですが。